# Scan table with multiple rowkey filter in hbase

Tags: hbase, row-key

I have tried with single row-key ,its working fine but i am unable to fetch multiple row-key scan.

```
scan 'LPV',{FILTER =>"(PrefixFilter('174','194')"}
```

getting error,find [Filter to support scan multiple row key ranges](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11144) but didnt find is it possible or not ? I want to fetch multiple records based on multiple row-keys. Any help,Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to OR two PrefixFilters
as in

```
scan 'LPV',{FILTER =>"(PrefixFilter('174') OR PrefixFilter('194')"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a solution in Hbase shell for multiple prefix filter.
But you can write a script to do multiple prefixfilter one by one.
for example put your key prefixes to a file a1.txt line by line;

```
a1.txt
-------
pref1
pref2
pref3
```

then run a script like (i am not good at shell scripting. you can do better)

```
cat a1.txt | while read LINE; do echo "scan 'LPV',{FILTER=>\"PrefixFilter('$LINE')\"} " | hbase shell;done
```